# gradle build is not working in linux

Tags: linux, gradle, build.gradle

So my gradle build file is working in Windows fine and all tests are passing. Now I am trying to get all my tests to pass in linux as well.

The following is a link to the repo: https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

I first install gradle with the following instructions:

```
unix> wget http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
unix> sudo unzip -q gradle-1.10-bin.zip -d /usr/local/
unix> echo "export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle-1.10" >> .profile
unix> echo "export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin" >> .profile
```

Then I navigate into the WalnutiQ folder after git cloning it.

After typing to the command line "gradle build --stacktrace" I get the following error:

```
[ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-10:~/Desktop/WalnutiQ]$gradle build --stacktrace                                                                 :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
Cause: Could not generate test report to '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WalnutiQ/build/reports/tests'.
Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':test'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.execute(AbstractTask.java:237)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:167)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:160)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskNameResolvingBuildExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.DelegatingBuildExecuter.execute(DelegatingBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
        at org.gradle.launcher.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.launcher.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:203)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate test report to '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WalnutiQ/build/reports/tests'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.DefaultTestReport.generateFiles(DefaultTestReport.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.DefaultTestReport.generateReport(DefaultTestReport.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestFramework.report(JUnitTestFramework.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:334)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:158)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$2.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$2.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:63)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.DefaultTestReport.copyResource(DefaultTestReport.java:168)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.DefaultTestReport.copyResources(DefaultTestReport.java:157)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.report.DefaultTestReport.generateFiles(DefaultTestReport.java:122)
        ... 38 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 7.262 secs
```

Comment: did you try with --info or --debug?  Does the directory exist?  Do you need the daemon to be running or something?

Comment: Are you sure that you have permission to generate anything to the `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/WalnutiQ/build/reports/tests`

Comment: I am using a amazon ec2 t1.micro instance. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be a permissions error? Try running as a super user (sudo) or installing gradle to somewhere within your complete control. Scanning through the source code, it would suggest its failing copy a file from gradle installation to the build directory of your project. So either the file is missing, or we are getting a permission issue.

Comment: I am using a amazon ec2 t1.micro instance. Is that the problem?

Comment: Tried running gradle as sudo? If possible try installing gradle somewhere in your home directory if sudo doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error but the files are all being written successfully. I can see them after I run the build.